# MariaDB - Archive Engine Missing

Tags: mariadb

I've just installed MariaDB 5.5 on Windows2k8 64bit, straight forward default install using the windows MSI installer.

If I do a SHOW ENGINES the ARCHIVE engine is missing. How can I include the ARCHIVE storage engine during or post install?

MikeW

Comment: Bump..Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We recently had the same problem and could solve it with the following procedure. First check the **lib/plugin/** folder for **ha_archive.dll**. This is the engine driver.

Now you can activate the plugin by adding the following line to your **my.ini**:

```
plugin-load=ha_archive
```

(If you don't have a **my.ini**, create it according to the example *.ini files in the root folder)

Don't forget to restart your mariadb instance.